# Ionic 2 - Turning HTTP GET JSON Response into an array of items

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on an app and am having difficulty using an API call to Eventbrite in a provider, parsing the JSON it returns, and inserting the data I want into an array.

Here is my provider (event-provider.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {NativeStorage} from "ionic-native";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the EventProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class EventProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log("Event Provider")
  }
  public getJsonData(){


    return this.http.get('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token=VMGQGYQUIO3IKNS75BD4').map(res => res.json().events);

  }
    //console.log('Hello EventProvider Provider');
}
```

And here is the event page in which I eventually will list the data (events.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {EventProvider} from '../../providers/event-provider';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'event-list',
  templateUrl: 'events.html',
  providers: [EventProvider]
})
export class EventsPage {
  events = []


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private eventProvider: EventProvider) {

    this.events = eventProvider.getJsonData();

  }

}
```

For the above .ts file I am getting an error at `this.events = eventProvider.getJsonData();`. The error says: *Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'find' is missing in type 'Observable'*. I do not really understand this error.

This is what the JSON response looks like: [EventBrite](https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token=VMGQGYQUIO3IKNS75BD4)

Basically, I want to add each event as an item to an array. The JSON response contains about 500 events.

I've just stuck at the moment an not sure if on on the right track. It is hard to debug my code because it is being tested in an iOS emulator and thus the console.log() doesn't work. Any tips on how to reach my goal of creating an array of events from the JSON response?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `subscribe` to observables in order to make a request.

```
this.events = eventProvider.getJsonData();
```

should be something like:

```
eventProvider.getJsonData().subscribe((res)=>{
  this.events = res.events;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And Also you need to return that json and assuming you always have event properties in the response:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {NativeStorage} from "ionic-native";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the EventProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class EventProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log("Event Provider")
  }
  public getJsonData(){


    return this.http.get('yourUrl')
         .map(res => {
               let body = res.json();
               return body.events || { };

           });

  }

}
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error at `eventProvider.getJsonData().subscribe((res)=>{` in events.ts saying *Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.*